# Can't open Xcode Template package (.xctemplate) with AppCode. Should I be able to?

Tags: xcode, templates, appcode

Hmmm. I've just tried to open an Xcode Template package `.xctemplate` using AppCode. Nothing is opened, and AppCode just returns to the welcome screen.

Anyone familiar with this in AppCode?

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough, it also doesn't appear as though Xcode can operate on Xcode Template packages.

So, I'm guessing this might prohibit AppCode from being able to deal with these.

I've opened "[OC-19343 Add Xcode Template editing in AppCode](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-19343)" with JetBrains to request this functionality.

Feel free to upvote the issue in JetBrains' YouTrack.